# Visual Basic Advanced Browser

Tags: vb.net, browser, visual-studio-2013

I am creating a browser in Visual Basic, but am having a problem saving my settings. 
In advanced options, under the privacy tab i would like to have my browser retain the settings after closing the window. If i click "Never Remember password", and close the window, the settings are not stored. 
Also, when I type a URL in, after searching the URL is not updated correctly.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how i can make these parts of my project work? 
I am somewhat new to coding, so any tips or extra ideas to add to the Browser would be welcomed and much appreciated as i would like to see this fully functional.

Thank you! :D

Form 1

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO


Public Class Magycka

Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal volumeUpOrDown As Byte, ByVal v1 As Byte, ByVal v2 As Integer, ByVal v3 As Integer)

Private Sub Magycka_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

    File.Delete("C:\Magycka\history.txt")

    For Each link As String In History.lstHistory.Items
        File.AppendAllText("C:\Magycka\History.txt", link & vbNewLine)
    Next

    For Each favoriteName As String In lstName.Items
        File.AppendAllText("C:\Magycka\favoriteName.txt", favoriteName & vbNewLine)
    Next

    For Each favoriteURL As String In lstURL.Items
        File.AppendAllText("C:\Magycka\favoriteURL.txt", favoriteURL & vbNewLine)
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub tmrDate_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrDate.Tick
    lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    cmbSearchEngine.Items.Add("Google")
    cmbSearchEngine.Items.Add("Google Images")
    cmbSearchEngine.Items.Add("YouTube")

    cmbSearchEngine.SelectedIndex = 0

    addTab(TabControl1)

    Try
        Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag
        txtURL.Text = browser.Url.ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try


    If My.Settings.homePageorBlankPage = 0 Then
        Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag
        browser.Navigate(My.Settings.homePage)
    Else
    End If

    Try

        History.Visible = False
        For Each link As String In File.ReadAllLines("C:\Magycka\history.txt")
            History.lstHistory.Items.Add(link.ToString)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    Try
        For Each url As String In File.ReadAllLines("C:\Magycka\favoriteURL.txt")
            ListBox3.Items.Add(url)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    Try
        ListBox3.SelectedIndex = 0
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    Try
        For Each Name As String In File.ReadAllLines("C:\Magycka\favoriteName.txt")
            Dim newBookmark As New ToolStripButton
            newBookmark.Text = Name

            newBookmark.Tag = ListBox3.SelectedItem.ToString
            tsBookmarks.Items.Add(newBookmark)
            ListBox3.SelectedIndex = ListBox3.SelectedIndex + 1

        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    createdBookClick()

End Sub



Private Sub txtURLsearchEngines_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtURLsearchEngines.KeyUp

    Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag

    Select Case (cmbSearchEngine.SelectedIndex)
        Case 0
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
                browser.Navigate("https://www.google.com/#q=" + txtURLsearchEngines.Text)
            End If
        Case 1
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
                browser.Navigate("https://www.google.com/search?site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1366&bih=661&q=" + txtURL.Text)
            End If
        Case 2
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
                browser.Navigate("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + txtURLsearchEngines.Text)
            End If
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub txtURL_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtURL.KeyUp
    Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        browser.Navigate(txtURL.Text)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click
    Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag
    browser.GoBack()
End Sub

Private Sub btnForward_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnForward.Click
    Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag
    browser.GoForward()
End Sub

Private Sub brnRefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles brnRefresh.Click
    Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag
    browser.Refresh()
End Sub

Private Sub btnURL_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnURL.Click
    Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag
    browser.Navigate(txtURL.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub btnVolumeUp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnVolumeUp.Click
    Call keybd_event(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.VolumeUp, 0, 0, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub btnVolumeDown_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnVolumeDown.Click
    Call keybd_event(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.VolumeDown, 0, 0, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub btnMute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMute.Click
    Call keybd_event(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.VolumeMute, 0, 0, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub OptionsToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OptionsToolStripMenuItem.Click
    AdvancedOptions.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub ViewHistoryToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ViewHistoryToolStripMenuItem.Click
    History.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub btnHome_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnHome.Click
    Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag
    browser.Navigate(My.Settings.homePage)
End Sub

Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag
    Select Case (cmbSearchEngine.SelectedIndex)
        Case 0
            browser.Navigate("https://www.google.com/#q=" + txtURLsearchEngines.Text)
        Case 1
            browser.Navigate("https://www.google.com/search?site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1366&bih=661&q=" = txtURLsearchEngines.Text)
        Case 2
            browser.Navigate("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + txtURLsearchEngines.Text)
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub NewTabToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NewTabToolStripMenuItem.Click
    addTab(TabControl1)
End Sub

Private Sub CloseTabToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CloseTabToolStripMenuItem.Click
    removeTab()
End Sub

Public Sub addTab(ByRef TabControl As TabControl)
    Dim browser As New webBrowserfunction
    Dim tab As New TabPage
    browser.Tag = tab
    tab.Tag = browser
    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tab)
    tab.Controls.Add(browser)
    browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    browser.Navigate(My.Settings.homePage)

    TabControl1.SelectedTab = tab

End Sub
Public Sub addTabfromHistory(ByRef TabControl As TabControl, ByRef link As String)

    Dim browser As New webBrowserfunction
    Dim tab As New TabPage
    browser.Tag = tab
    tab.Tag = browser
    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tab)
    tab.Controls.Add(browser)
    browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    browser.Navigate(link)

    TabControl1.SelectedTab = tab

End Sub

Public Sub removeTab()
    If TabControl1.TabPages.Count <> 0 Then
        TabControl1.TabPages.Remove(TabControl1.SelectedTab)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag

    Try
        txtURL.Text = browser.Url.ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub NewToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NewToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim newWindow As New Magycka
    newWindow.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub UndoToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UndoToolStripMenuItem.Click
    txtURL.Undo()
End Sub

Private Sub RedoToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RedoToolStripMenuItem.Click
    txtURL.ClearUndo()
End Sub

Private Sub CutToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CutToolStripMenuItem.Click
    txtURL.Cut()
End Sub

Private Sub CopyToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CopyToolStripMenuItem.Click
    txtURL.Copy()
End Sub

Private Sub PasteToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PasteToolStripMenuItem.Click
    txtURL.Paste()
End Sub

Private Sub SelectAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    txtURL.SelectAll()
End Sub

Private Sub SaveSourceCodeToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveSourceCodeToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag
    Dim fileName As String = InputBox("Enter FileName:", "Save HTML", ".txt")
    Dim path As String = "C:\Magycka\" & fileName

    Try
        If File.Exists(path) Then
            Dim allText As String
            allText = browser.DocumentText
            File.WriteAllText(path, allText)
        Else
            File.Create(path).Dispose()
            Dim allText As String
            allText = browser.DocumentText
            File.WriteAllText(path, allText)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub addBookmarks()
    Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag
    Dim newBookmark As New ToolStripButton

    newBookmark.Text = TabControl1.SelectedTab.Text
    newBookmark.Tag = browser.Url
    tsBookmarks.Items.Add(newBookmark)
    lstName.Items.Add(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Text)
    lstURL.Items.Add(browser.Url.ToString)

    AddHandler newBookmark.Click, AddressOf newBookmarkClick


End Sub

Private Sub newBookmarkClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag

    If TypeOf sender Is ToolStripButton Then
        browser.Navigate(CType(sender, ToolStripButton).Tag)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub createdBookClick()
    For Each item As ToolStripButton In tsBookmarks.Items
        AddHandler item.Click, AddressOf bookClick
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub bookClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    txtURL.Text = CType(sender, ToolStripButton).Tag
    bookNav()
End Sub

Private Sub bookNav()
    Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag
    browser.Navigate(txtURL.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub BookmarkPageToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BookmarkPageToolStripMenuItem.Click
    addBookmarks()
End Sub

End Class
```

Advanced Options

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO


Public Class Magycka

Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal volumeUpOrDown As Byte, ByVal v1 As Byte, ByVal v2 As Integer, ByVal v3 As Integer)

Private Sub Magycka_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing

    File.Delete("C:\Magycka\history.txt")

    For Each link As String In History.lstHistory.Items
        File.AppendAllText("C:\Magycka\History.txt", link & vbNewLine)
    Next

    For Each favoriteName As String In lstName.Items
        File.AppendAllText("C:\Magycka\favoriteName.txt", favoriteName & vbNewLine)
    Next

    For Each favoriteURL As String In lstURL.Items
        File.AppendAllText("C:\Magycka\favoriteURL.txt", favoriteURL & vbNewLine)
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub tmrDate_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmrDate.Tick
    lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    cmbSearchEngine.Items.Add("Google")
    cmbSearchEngine.Items.Add("Google Images")
    cmbSearchEngine.Items.Add("YouTube")

    cmbSearchEngine.SelectedIndex = 0

    addTab(TabControl1)

    Try
        Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag
        txtURL.Text = browser.Url.ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try


    If My.Settings.homePageorBlankPage = 0 Then
        Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag
        browser.Navigate(My.Settings.homePage)
    Else
    End If

    Try

        History.Visible = False
        For Each link As String In File.ReadAllLines("C:\Magycka\history.txt")
            History.lstHistory.Items.Add(link.ToString)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    Try
        For Each url As String In File.ReadAllLines("C:\Magycka\favoriteURL.txt")
            ListBox3.Items.Add(url)
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    Try
        ListBox3.SelectedIndex = 0
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    Try
        For Each Name As String In File.ReadAllLines("C:\Magycka\favoriteName.txt")
            Dim newBookmark As New ToolStripButton
            newBookmark.Text = Name

            newBookmark.Tag = ListBox3.SelectedItem.ToString
            tsBookmarks.Items.Add(newBookmark)
            ListBox3.SelectedIndex = ListBox3.SelectedIndex + 1

        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    createdBookClick()

End Sub



Private Sub txtURLsearchEngines_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtURLsearchEngines.KeyUp

    Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag

    Select Case (cmbSearchEngine.SelectedIndex)
        Case 0
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
                browser.Navigate("https://www.google.com/#q=" + txtURLsearchEngines.Text)
            End If
        Case 1
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
                browser.Navigate("https://www.google.com/search?site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1366&bih=661&q=" + txtURL.Text)
            End If
        Case 2
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
                browser.Navigate("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + txtURLsearchEngines.Text)
            End If
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub txtURL_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtURL.KeyUp
    Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        browser.Navigate(txtURL.Text)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click
    Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag
    browser.GoBack()
End Sub

Private Sub btnForward_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnForward.Click
    Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag
    browser.GoForward()
End Sub

Private Sub brnRefresh_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles brnRefresh.Click
    Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag
    browser.Refresh()
End Sub

Private Sub btnURL_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnURL.Click
    Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag
    browser.Navigate(txtURL.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub btnVolumeUp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnVolumeUp.Click
    Call keybd_event(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.VolumeUp, 0, 0, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub btnVolumeDown_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnVolumeDown.Click
    Call keybd_event(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.VolumeDown, 0, 0, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub btnMute_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMute.Click
    Call keybd_event(System.Windows.Forms.Keys.VolumeMute, 0, 0, 0)
End Sub

Private Sub OptionsToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles OptionsToolStripMenuItem.Click
    AdvancedOptions.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub ViewHistoryToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ViewHistoryToolStripMenuItem.Click
    History.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub btnHome_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnHome.Click
    Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag
    browser.Navigate(My.Settings.homePage)
End Sub

Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = Me.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag
    Select Case (cmbSearchEngine.SelectedIndex)
        Case 0
            browser.Navigate("https://www.google.com/#q=" + txtURLsearchEngines.Text)
        Case 1
            browser.Navigate("https://www.google.com/search?site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1366&bih=661&q=" = txtURLsearchEngines.Text)
        Case 2
            browser.Navigate("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + txtURLsearchEngines.Text)
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub NewTabToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NewTabToolStripMenuItem.Click
    addTab(TabControl1)
End Sub

Private Sub CloseTabToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CloseTabToolStripMenuItem.Click
    removeTab()
End Sub

Public Sub addTab(ByRef TabControl As TabControl)
    Dim browser As New webBrowserfunction
    Dim tab As New TabPage
    browser.Tag = tab
    tab.Tag = browser
    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tab)
    tab.Controls.Add(browser)
    browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    browser.Navigate(My.Settings.homePage)

    TabControl1.SelectedTab = tab

End Sub
Public Sub addTabfromHistory(ByRef TabControl As TabControl, ByRef link As String)

    Dim browser As New webBrowserfunction
    Dim tab As New TabPage
    browser.Tag = tab
    tab.Tag = browser
    TabControl1.TabPages.Add(tab)
    tab.Controls.Add(browser)
    browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    browser.Navigate(link)

    TabControl1.SelectedTab = tab

End Sub

Public Sub removeTab()
    If TabControl1.TabPages.Count <> 0 Then
        TabControl1.TabPages.Remove(TabControl1.SelectedTab)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag

    Try
        txtURL.Text = browser.Url.ToString
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub NewToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NewToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim newWindow As New Magycka
    newWindow.Show()
End Sub

Private Sub UndoToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UndoToolStripMenuItem.Click
    txtURL.Undo()
End Sub

Private Sub RedoToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RedoToolStripMenuItem.Click
    txtURL.ClearUndo()
End Sub

Private Sub CutToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CutToolStripMenuItem.Click
    txtURL.Cut()
End Sub

Private Sub CopyToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CopyToolStripMenuItem.Click
    txtURL.Copy()
End Sub

Private Sub PasteToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PasteToolStripMenuItem.Click
    txtURL.Paste()
End Sub

Private Sub SelectAllToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    txtURL.SelectAll()
End Sub

Private Sub SaveSourceCodeToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveSourceCodeToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag
    Dim fileName As String = InputBox("Enter FileName:", "Save HTML", ".txt")
    Dim path As String = "C:\Magycka\" & fileName

    Try
        If File.Exists(path) Then
            Dim allText As String
            allText = browser.DocumentText
            File.WriteAllText(path, allText)
        Else
            File.Create(path).Dispose()
            Dim allText As String
            allText = browser.DocumentText
            File.WriteAllText(path, allText)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub addBookmarks()
    Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag
    Dim newBookmark As New ToolStripButton

    newBookmark.Text = TabControl1.SelectedTab.Text
    newBookmark.Tag = browser.Url
    tsBookmarks.Items.Add(newBookmark)
    lstName.Items.Add(TabControl1.SelectedTab.Text)
    lstURL.Items.Add(browser.Url.ToString)

    AddHandler newBookmark.Click, AddressOf newBookmarkClick


End Sub

Private Sub newBookmarkClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag

    If TypeOf sender Is ToolStripButton Then
        browser.Navigate(CType(sender, ToolStripButton).Tag)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub createdBookClick()
    For Each item As ToolStripButton In tsBookmarks.Items
        AddHandler item.Click, AddressOf bookClick
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub bookClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    txtURL.Text = CType(sender, ToolStripButton).Tag
    bookNav()
End Sub

Private Sub bookNav()
    Dim browser As webBrowserfunction = TabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag
    browser.Navigate(txtURL.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub BookmarkPageToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BookmarkPageToolStripMenuItem.Click
    addBookmarks()
End Sub

End Class
```

History

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class History

Private Sub History_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    e.Cancel = True
    Me.Visible = False

    For Each link As String In lstHistory.Items
        File.AppendAllText("C:\Magycka\History.txt", link & vbNewLine)
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub btnClearHis_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClearHis.Click
    lstHistory.Items.Clear()
    System.IO.File.Delete("C:\Magycka\History.txt")
End Sub

Private Sub btnCloseHis_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCloseHis.Click
    For Each link As String In lstHistory.Items
        File.AppendAllText("C:\Magycka\History.txt", link & vbNewLine)
    Next
    Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    lstHistory.Items.Remove(lstHistory.SelectedItem)
End Sub

Private Sub lstHistory_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles lstHistory.MouseDoubleClick
    Magycka.addTabfromHistory(Magycka.TabControl1, lstHistory.SelectedItem.ToString)

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Are you talking about saving/storing user options as in My.Settings?  That is one giant wall of code for an [MCVE]

Comment: Correct. 
i'd like to save it as My.Settings.enablePrivateBrowsing, in form_closing but it will not let me due to it being a Byte.
I would post a picture, but alas i cannot yet.

Comment: [Edit] your post to just the pertinent code. I cant find where you might be trying to do that.

Comment: Editted! 
in My.Settings i have it specified as enablePrivateBrowsing, set as a byte.
The saves here work but are for changing the home page.
The code i have works but does not save the changes, i have to keep the seperate form open for it to work.

Comment: apply the checkmark value to settings in the Formclosing event...also use Boolean not Byte. `My.Settings.privateBrowsing = chkPrivate.Checked`

Comment: but what if i wanted to change the value and save it like as a toggle option? I dont want to just set it to one.

Comment: you've completely lost me. is it not a checkbox (on/off)?  if not what is it?

Comment: they are radio buttons. it works, but as soon as i close the form it goes back to default and does not keep the settings.

Comment: Of course the form forgets them, Settings is for saving...well, settings between app runs.  I also would not use My.Settings for variable storage.  For RBs you will need to evaluate which one is selected and save an integer value (not bool or byte), or assign some Text to the .Tag property and save that as string.

Comment: instead of using radio buttons, i ended up using a combo box and got it to work!